# Codeigniter - Sending email

Tags: php, codeigniter

i try to send email with codeigniter on localhost.

In order to that, in config directory i open a new php file called email

and write

```
<?php

$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'mertmetinbjk@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'pass',
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);

?>
```

and in my controller write this

```
$this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from('bildirim@pasaj.com','Pasaj.com');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('pasaj hesabinizi aktive etmek icin');
        $this->email->message('Tıkla');
        $this->email->send();
```

but i get these errors:

[image]

i made some research on the Internet, i read that i have to enable ssl from my php.ini file but there is no line like what can i do ?

TY

Comment: Try also using TLS instead (can't remember the port right now)

Comment: there is no line like that in my php.ini file

Comment: @MertMETİN: Is this on Windows or Linux? If Windows, you need to install [OpenSSL for Windows](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) and uncomment `extension=php_openssl.dll` in your `php.ini`.

Comment: i use win but in my php.ini file there no extension=php_openssl.dll line :S

Comment: @MertMETİN: Is that `.dll` file in your `path/to/php/ext/` folder? If it is, you should just be able to add `extension=php_openssl.dll` whee your other extensions are listed in your `php.ini` and then restart Apache.

Comment: pff i c/p them to ext folder still doesnt seem the php_openssl.dll

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

instead of this:

```
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

Your controller would look like this:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('bildirim@pasaj.com','Pasaj.com');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject('pasaj hesabinizi aktive etmek icin');
$this->email->message('Tıkla');
$this->email->send();
```

Perhaps it's a good thing to post the answer you got from the [CodeIgniter Forums](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/132443/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$email =$this->input->post('email');
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('bildirim@pasaj.com','Pasaj.com');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject('pasaj hesabinizi aktive etmek icin');
$this->email->message('Tıkla');
$this->email->send();
```